# Parsing JSON text through ADF into SQL with "legitimate" escape characters in the string

Tags: sql, json

I am using ADF to access an API, the response is added to a single column in a SQL table.  The json_response is then transformed into columns and rows.  However, in the JSON response there are characters such as " or : or ' or < { } = ? etc that the product owner claims should legitimately be there.

And example of part the json response is:

"Name": "Registration: Update for renewal on Premises",
or
"Name": "Harry Potter "{}<>+?"

How can I process the JSON into SQL where it would process these responses.  I recognise that in the 2nd example, other than replace(XXX,'"{}<>+','') for every instance there may be a better suggestion.

The error message I receive is "JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ':' is found at position XX"

The SQL script I have essentially is:

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(MAX) = 'declare @Var VARCHAR(MAX) select @Var = JsonResponse from dbo.JsonResponse SELECT '

SET @STRING = @STRING + 'JSON_VALUE(value,''$.' + @ColKey + ''') as ' + @ColName + IIF(@CNT = @MAX, @Audit + ' from openjson(@Var) ',',')
```

This script works as planned AS LONG as the data is clean.

Thankyou, I am using ADF and Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: What is ADF in this context?

Comment: I guess you need to validate the vendor's JSON against some kind of JSON standard (if such a thing exists). I would at the _very least_ expect the `"` to be escaped like this : `"Name": "Harry Potter \"{}<>+?"`

Comment: @Dai - Azure Data Factory/Synapse

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - thankyou, do I work out some replace function to replace ONLY the " inside a string with the \" before the processing, BUT NOT all of the other " 's that signify the start and end of the column/value?  Thanks

Comment: No. You can't do it because the data is now ambiguous. Only the vendor creating the file actually knows which quotes need to be escaped. The vendor has not created a valid JSON file. Perhaps pass this example on to them.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - thankyou - I will push back on this.  Thankyou.

Comment: This is probably not authoritative, but if you go to https://jsonlint.com/ and paste in `{"Name": "Harry Potter "{}<>+?"}`, it's not valid. If you paste in `{"Name": \"Harry Potter "{}<>+?"}` it is.